# Can we declare an empty function in a for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, for-loop

```
def dec_list():
    a = list()
    for i in range(0, 3):
        i = int(input("Enter the values: "))
        a.append(i)
    print(a)
x = dec_list()
print(x)
output:
[1,2,3]
```

```
total = 0
for num in x:
    total = total + num
    print(total)
output:
    for num in x:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Regarding the first part of the code, my output is working ( i.e [1,2,3] ), but when I'm trying to run the for loop with a function there's an error which occurs.
Can you please help me with this problem?

(Sorry if the pattern of asking my question is inappropriate, it's my first time)

Thank you!

Comment: You need to describe the thing you're doing and how it's not working.  What's the code you're running when you "run the for loop with a function", and what exactly is the error you get?  (Just copy and paste that into your question.)

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```
total = 0
for num in x:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware that when `print` something inside the function, it is not the output! Hence, the output of `dec_list` function is `None`, not as you mentioned.

To work with your second code, you need to return the list inside the function. So, you need to rewrite the function likes the following:

```
def dec_list():
    a = list()
    for i in range(0, 3):
        i = int(input("Enter the values: "))
        a.append(i)
    print(a)
    return a # this line I mean
x = dec_list()
```

Now the second part can be run without any error.

Comment: Thank you so much! I understood my mistake

Comment: @Ramnishanth my pleasure. You can accept this as your solution.